# Execute Sql query in entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a jquery data table in which i want to show a summarise report generated from sql query, but i am not able to do it, it shows error in the query. The summarise report consist of all month name and number of entries in every month.

Error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DHIFeedbackModel.FeedBack'. A member of the type, 'FeedbackUserName', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

```
public ActionResult LoadData()
{
    using (DHIFeedbackEntities2 Ms = new DHIFeedbackEntities2())
    {

        //var summary = Ms.FeedBacks.SqlQuery("select * from [DHIFeedback].[dbo].[FeedBack]").ToList<FeedBack>();
        var summary = Ms.FeedBacks.SqlQuery(
            @"SELECT * 
            FROM 
                (
                SELECT 
                    YEAR([FeedBackDate])[Year],DATENAME(MONTH, [FeedBackDate])[Month],
                    COUNT(1)[FeedbackID] 
                FROM 
                    [DHIFeedback].[dbo].[FeedBack] 
                GROUP BY 
                    YEAR([FeedBackDate]
                ),
                DATENAME(MONTH, [FeedBackDate])) AS Monthlyupdate 
                PIVOT(SUM([FeedbackID]) FOR Month IN([January],[February],[March],[April],[May],[June],[July],[August],[September],[October],[November],[December])) AS MNamePivot 
            order by 1,2"
        ).FirstOrDefault<FeedBack>();
        return Json(new { data = summary }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


    }
}
```

and the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Summary').DataTable({

                "processing": true,

                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Summary/LoadData",
                    "type": "GET",
                    "datatype": "json",

                },
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
                    [5, 10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
                ],
                "autoWidth": true,
                "responsive": true,
                "lengthChange": true,
                "ordering": true,
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                    var oSettings = this.fnSettings();
                    $("td:first", nRow).html(oSettings._iDisplayStart + iDisplayIndex + 1);
                    return nRow;
                },
                "columns": [

                    { "data":"Year", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"January", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"February", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"March", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"April", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"May", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"June", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"July", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"August", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"September", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"October", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"November", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data":"December", "autoWidth": true }
                ]
            });
        });


 public partial class FeedBack
    {
        public int FeedbackID { get; set; }
        public string FeedbackUserName { get; set; }
        public string FeedBackUserEmailID { get; set; }
        public string FeedBackComment { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string Organization { get; set; }
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FeedBackDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> IsPublished { get; set; }
        public string Reply { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> IsReplied { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReplyDate { get; set; }
        public string ReplyBy { get; set; }
        public string Sector { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Status { get; set; }

        public int Year { get; set; }
        public int January { get; set; }
        public int February { get; set; }
        public int March { get; set; }
        public int April { get; set; }
        public int May { get; set; }
        public int June { get; set; }
        public int July { get; set; }
        public int August { get; set; }
        public int September { get; set; }
        public int October { get; set; }
        public int November { get; set; }
        public int December { get; set; }
        public string Monthlyupdate { get; set; }
        public string Month{ get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public List<FeedBack> FeedBackCollection { get; set; }
```

Comment: You're using an ORM. Why do you want to write your own SQL query instead of just using the ORM?

Comment: can you resolve my issue

Comment: What is the error? ??

Comment: @sunnykumar the *issue* is that a complex query is embedded in the code. Put it in a view or stored procedure instead, so you can evolve it and optimize it separately.

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DHIFeedbackModel.FeedBack'. A member of the type, 'FeedbackUserName', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

Comment: @sunnykumar edit your question and format it so people can read it, and add the error *in the question itself*. The query is hidden right now, there's a Javascript block that has nothing to do with EF. If people can't read the query, they can't see what may be missing.

Comment: @sunnykumar if the error complains about the `FeedBack` type, post it in the question. The error seems to say that you forgot to load a required property. If you used the context's configuration to specify that `FeedbackUserName` is required, post the context configuration as well

Comment: But i am able to see the query in my question, the query contains month name which are not generated at run time, i want to show those columns in jquery datatable

Answer (score 0):

the error means that the ORM is expecting a resultset comprising each and every property of `FeedBacks` including the one named `FeedbackUserName`

So you need to edit the select clause of your sql to return all the expected columns.

or you may use

```
Ms.Database.SqlQuery<SomeType>(
                   "your query here").ToList();
```

where `SomeType` is :

```
public class SomeType {
    public int Year {get; set;}        
    //... and/or all the pivoted columns
}
```

Comment: But the columns i need, and the expected output which i require are only generated from this query.

Comment: Still it shows the same issue, i tried public int year {get:set;}, public int january{get:set:}

Comment: you should have a different member name in the error message

Comment: 'The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'DHIFeedbackModel.FeedBack'. A member of the type, 'FeedbackID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.'

Comment: i have the model class in the above code , u can see that as well

Comment: from your quote you are still referencing `DHIFeedbackModel.FeedBack`in your query. Are you sure to use `Ms.Database.SqlQuery<SomeType>`and not `Ms.FeedBacks.SqlQuery`

Comment: when i use Ms.Database.sqlQuery<string> , it says "The non generic method 'Dbset<Feedback'>.sqlquery(string) cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: you can't use `<string>` you must declare a type/class as the result of your query.

Comment: `string feedbacklist = Ms.Database.SqlQuery<string>("select [FeedbackUserName],[FeedBackUserEmailID],[FeedBackComment],[Designation],[Organization],[ContactNo],[City],[FeedBackDate] from [DHIFeedback].[dbo].[FeedBack]").ToList<FeedBack>();`  should i use the query like this.. but its telling me to use  `FirstorDefault()` instead of to list.

Comment: you can't use `string` as return type, you must use a specific type `class myType { string FeedbackUserName {get; set;} /*...*/ }`